# Meaning of backslash in Haskell code?

Tags: haskell, syntax

So I have this haskell code, and I understand half of it, but I can't get my head around this `\x ->` here:

```
testDB :: Catalogue
testDB = fromList [
 ("0265090316581", ("The Macannihav'nmor Highland Single Malt", "75ml bottle")),
 ("0903900739533", ("Bagpipes of Glory", "6-CD Box")),
 ("9780201342758", ("Thompson - \"Haskell: The Craft of Functional Programming\"", "Book")),
 ("0042400212509", ("Universal deep-frying pan", "pc"))
 ]


-- Exercise 1

longestProductLen :: [(Barcode, Item)] -> Int
longestProductLen = maximum . map (\(x, y) -> length $ fst y) 

formatLine :: Int -> (Barcode, Item) -> String
formatLine k (x, (y1, y2)) = x ++ "..." ++ y1 ++ (take  (k - length y1) (repeat '.')) ++ "..." ++ y2

showCatalogue :: Catalogue -> String
showCatalogue c = foldr (++) "" $ map (\x -> (formatLine (longestProductLen (toList testDB)) x) ++ "\n") $ toList c
```

I understand that `longestProductLen` returns and integer meaning the longest title in `testDB` and then it uses this integer to match `k` in `formatLine`, but I can't understnad how it matches `(Bardcode, Item)` and I guess it has something to do with `\x ->`, if it does can you please explain how it does that?

Thank you!

Comment: `\x -> ...` is a way to define a (unnamed) function - in this case (I guess you are talking about `showCatalogue` here?) `x` will *see* every element in `toList c` and use `formatLine (...` to *map* it into some other value and all those values will be a list with the same order again ... I mean this is really basic stuff - maybe you can make your question a bit more concrete?

Comment: @Carsten yes, that's the one

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The syntax

```
function x y = <body>
```

Is equivalent to

```
function = \x y -> <body>
```

And is called a lambda or anonymous function.  The compiler actually turns all your functions into assignments of lambda functions (the second form) since it's just giving a function value (functions are values in Haskell) a name.

If you see it given as an argument to another function like `map`:

```
map (\x -> x + 1) [1, 2, 3]
```

This is semantically equivalent to

```
map add1 [1, 2, 3] where add1 x = x + 1
```

Lambdas can perform arbitrary pattern matching on their arguments, too.  Also, if you have a definition like

```
fib 0 = 1
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n - 1) + fib (n - 2)
```

This is equivalent to

```
fib = \n -> case n of
    0 -> 1
    1 -> 1
    n -> fib (n - 1) + fib (n - 2)
```

Because the compiler will first translate the multiple pattern matching into a case statement, then convert it to assigning a lambda to a name (in this case assigning the lambda to the name `fib`).

Comment: So this whole code `(\x -> (formatLine (longestProductLen (toList testDB)) x) ++ "\n")` defines a function with parameter `toList c` which returns a list and then maps `x` to every element from the `toList c` list ?

Comment: It defines a function with the parameter `x` which it then passes to the function `formatLine (longestProductionLen (toList testDB))`, which returns a `String` (a list of `Char`s), since the next step is `++ "\n"`.

Comment: `longestProductionLen (toList testDB)` returns an `int` and second parameter `x` must be of type `(Barcode, Item)` to get matched with `formatLine`. But how does `x` get assigned with each element ?

Comment: @southpaw93, `map` calls the anonymous function with each element of the list. I think you should really be working through tutorials instead of random code you found somewhere.

Comment: @dfeuer that's what I was thinking but I wasn't sure and wanted to verify, so map does that, now it's clear :) thanks.

Comment: @southpaw93 The function `(\x -> (formatLine ... x) ++ "\n")` is being passed as an argument to the function `map`.  The `map` function takes a function and a list, applies that function to each item of the list and returns a list of all those results.

Answer (score 8):

That's Haskell's syntax for lambda abstraction. The Haskell

```
\x -> e
```

corresponds to the mathematical

```
λx.e
```

In this case,

```
\(x, y) -> length $ fst y
```

is a function that takes a pair `(x,y)` and returns the length of the first component of the pair `y`. This is a slightly odd way to write the expression; it would be better to write it as

```
\(x, (y1, y2)) -> length y1
```

or as

```
length . fst . snd
```

for consistency.